# How to "leave" a group chat?

Tags: iphone

I want to stop receiving messages from a certain group chat I've been made a part of. I don't want to simply "hide alerts" from it, I don't want the messages to come in at all. Is there any way to do that? Deleting the conversation doesn't seem to help.